# Дерево сценариев в telegram-боте (строгая последовательность вопросов/ответов)

Tags: алгоритм, telegram-bot, любой-язык

Делаю чат-бота для телеграм. На данный момент есть многомерное меню, которое работает на `callback`-ах инлайнкнопок. Все бы было хорошо, но есть проблема: к примеру, человек нажимает <kbd>заказать</kbd>, затем выбирает товар. Затем ему нужно ввести адрес и время доставки, а также телефон и тд.

Скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это можно сделать? Т.е. если человек просто введет адрес доставки, то ему будет выдаваться "*не выбран товар*" или "*ошибка*", а если он выберет товар, то он пойдет по этому сценарию и так далее.

Вопрос - как сделать сценарий?

---

Мой код (*на примере `php`, библиотека `telegram-bot-sdk`*):

```
<?php
    DEFINE('ROOT', 'root const here');
    require_once(ROOT.'components/Db.php');
    require_once(ROOT.'models/Product.php');
    include('vendor/autoload.php'); //include telegram-bot-sdk
    use Telegram\Bot\Api; 
    use Telegram\Bot\Keyboard\Keyboard;
    use Telegram\Bot\Actions;
    use Telegram\Bot\Commands\Command;
    use Telegram\Bot\Objects\CallbackQuery;

    $telegram = new Api('api token here'); //Устанавливаем токен, полученный у BotFather

    $result = $telegram -> getWebhookUpdates(); //Передаем в переменную $result полную информацию о сообщении пользователя

    $keyboard = Keyboard::make()
    ->inline()
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Показать меню', 'callback_data' => '/show_menu']),
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Купить цветы', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers'])        
    );
    $keyboard_flowers = Keyboard::make()
    ->inline()
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Розы', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers_roses'])
    )
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Пионы', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers_piony'])
    )
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Шляпные коробки', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers_hatbox'])
    )
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Коробочки со сладостями', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers_sweetbox'])
    )
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Акции и спецпредложения', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers_sales'])
    );
    $keyboard_menu = Keyboard::make()
    ->inline()
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Связаться с нами', 'callback_data' => '/contact_us'])        
    )
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Купить цветы', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers'])
    )
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Стать партнером', 'callback_data' => '/partner'])
    )
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Перейти на сайт', 'url' => 'https://kands.spb.ru/']) 
    )
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Акции и спецпредложения', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers_sales'])  
    );
    $contact = $result['message']['contact'];
    $text = $result["message"]["text"]; //Текст сообщения
    $chat_id = $result["message"]["chat"]["id"];    
    $name = $result["message"]["from"]["username"]; //Юзернейм пользователя
    if ($result->isType('callback_query')) {
        $data = $result['callback_query']['data'];
        $chat = $result['callback_query']['message']['chat']['id'];
        switch ($data) {
            case '/buyflowers':
                $telegram->sendMessage([
                    'chat_id' => $chat,
                    'text' => 'Выберите категорию:', 
                    'reply_markup' => $keyboard_flowers
                ]);
                break;
            case '/show_menu':
                $telegram->sendMessage([
                    'chat_id' => $chat,
                    'text' => 'Меню: ', 
                    'reply_markup' => $keyboard_menu
                ]);
                break;

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }        
    }


    $telegram->sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => 'Стартовая страница. Выберите дальнейшие действия.',
        'reply_markup' => $keyboard
    ]);




?>
`
```

Comment: поскольку стабильно раз в неделю/две задаются аналогичные вопросы (и тревоги при этом часто отклоняются), предлагаю сделать вопрос общим и адаптировать его соответственно

Comment: @Anatol если видите вопрос, ответ на который уже есть в другом вопросе — отмечайте дубликатом (вроде бы вы уже так и делаете). Сделать общим чей-то вопрос можно только по заявке автора.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обработка текста из команды Telegram на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746598/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-telegram-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)

Comment: @ПавелДурманов как это может быть дубликатом, если этот вопрос старше на несколько месяцев? пометьте дубликатом тот, по вашей ссылке

Comment: @Anatol это не отменяет того факта, что это дубликат. И там можно найти ответ

Comment: @ПавелДурманов так себе логика. То есть вы предлагаете этот вопрос закрыть как дубликат, потому что есть похожий, даже не смотря на то, что он был задан позже этого?

Comment: @Anatol а не предлагаю его закрыть, просто говорю что дубликат. А так как в вопросе написано "любой язык" то всё верно.

Comment: @ПавелДурманов то есть вы не отмечали вопрос тревогой? Пометка вопроса *дубликатом* является основанием для его закрытия. Для декларируемых вами целей есть понятие *связанный вопрос*

Comment: @Anatol естно говоря не помню отвечал ли тревогой

Comment: @ПавелДурманов подсказка - комментарии идентичные вашему (про дубликат) являются автогенерируемыми и появляются автоматически после тревоги на вопросе. И да, все свои тревоги можно посмотреть в профиле

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Есть как минимум три варианта (*варианты можно совмещать*):

1. **Используйте коллекцию типа *ключ-значение***, где в качестве ключа используется *chat_id*, а в качестве значения - произвольный идентификатор предыдущего/следующего шага сценария (*концептуально, это могут вообще абсолютно любые необходимые данные*). Получив очередное сообщение от пользователя, сверяйте статус сценария со значением элемента коллекции для данного чата
2. **Используйте
   [*ForseReply*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply) при
   отправке сообщений** с запросами адреса и пр., а затем проверяйте
   входящие сообщения на наличие непустого поля ***reply_to_message***
   и смотрите в текст этого поля. В зависимости от его содержимого
   можно будет понять, какой именно шаг сценария выполняется
3. **Используйте встроенные кнопки (*[Inline buttons](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton)*)**. ***Inline button*** отличается от обычной кнопки тем, что не отправляет текст в чат. Вместо этого отправляется ***callback***, заданный программно и невидимый пользователю. Соответственно, в качестве ***callback_data*** можно использовать любой текст (*типа **step1** или **this_is_unexpected_step***), ожидая затем нужный коллбэк при получении обновлений

---

**Пример для варианта с *ForseReply*** (*псевдокод*):

```
// Производится запрос адреса пользователя
Bot.SendChatAction(update.Message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);
Bot.SendTextMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Укажите адрес доставки", replyMarkup: force_reply);
 ... 
// Проверка полученных сообщений от пользователя
if (update.Message.ReplyToMessage.Text.Contains("адрес доставки"))
{
    if (!IsValidAddress(update.Message.ReplyToMessage.Text)) return;
    SaveAddressToDb(update.Message.Chat.Id, update.Message.ReplyToMessage.Text);
    Bot.SendChatAction(update.Message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);
    Bot.SendTextMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Адрес успешно сохранён, ожидайте поступления заказа");
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

---

[Похожий вопрос на en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639923/telegram-bot-to-wait-for-user-reply)