# Как получить сообщение от юзера?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Имеется бот Telegram. Пишу на Python с использованием Telebot.Такой код:

```
if message.text == "Помочь советом":
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напишите Ваш совет")
    ????
```

Как осуществить ожидание сообщения от юзера? При использовании message.text получаю "помочь советом", а надо то, что введет юзер после появления "Напишите Ваш совет"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дерево сценариев в telegram-боте php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683506/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-php)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684728/183842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы таким образом хотите сделать блокировку бота, чтобы ждать в хэндлере ответа пользователя - не надо так. запомните предыдущий ответ, например:

```
prevAnswer = message.text
```

И получается будем ждать момента, когда следующий раз сработает хэндлер, и проверяем:

```
if "Помочь советом" in prevAnswer:
    # здесь в messge.text поидее и имеем текст совета от пользователя
```

А вообще я бы советовал вам прочитать про [Finite State Machine](http://www.python-course.eu/finite_state_machine.php) и реализовать алгоритм бота с применением данной абстракции.

Answer (score 2):

Вот [тут](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py) есть хороший пример как это реализовать. Смысл такой, что бот отвечает на сообщение и сохраняет в новый объект все параметры, потом ими можно манипулировать

Comment: Было бы неплохо, добавить в ответ основное из ссылки. Ответы соостоящие только из ссылки, ответами не считаются и обычно удаляются.