# Последовательные вопросы в Telegram bot на Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, yield

Доброго времени суток, есть желание сделать небольшой опросник в Telegram боте.
Идея такя, бот задает вопрос, пользователь отвечает и бот задает следующий вопрос, получает ответ и отправляет ответы постом на серевер.
Столкнулся с тем что не могу реализовать последовательность вывода вопросов сразу после ответа пользователя.
Пытался реализовать через генераторы но ничего не вышло.
Может кто-то что-то подскажет куда копать.

```
 function* gen() {
 let ask1 = yield bot.sendMessage(id, "Вопрос 1?");
  bot.on("message", msg => {
      fname = msg.text;
    });

  let ask2 = yield bot.sendMessage(id, "Вопрос 2?");
      bot.on("message", msg => {
        sname = msg.text;});
  }
```

Comment: А как вы вызываете этот генератор. Здесь первый обработчик сообщения будет устанавливаться только при втором вызове генератора. Это нормально? И ask1, ask2 нигде в генераторе не используются.

Comment: Я пытался так но после первого вопроса тишина
`
function* gen() {
 let ask1 = yield bot.sendMessage(id, "Вопрос 1?");
  bot.on("message", msg => {
      fname = msg.text;
   generator.next();
    });

  let ask2 = yield bot.sendMessage(id, "Вопрос 2?");
      bot.on("message", msg => {
        sname = msg.text;});
  }

let generator = gen();

bot.sendMessage(id, "Пройди опрос");
generator.next();`

Comment: Вызов generator.next() вызывает исполнение половины первой строки генератора **yield bot.sendMessage(id, "Вопрос 1?")** после чего генератор ожидает следующего вызова generator.next(здесь значение, которое положится в ask1) и только при этом втором вызове в генераторе дойдет управление до установки обработчика.

Comment: А что нужно положить в generator.next() первого вызова, что бы запустить ask2?

Comment: Чтобы дойти в генераторе до ask2 нужно два раза вызвать generator.next(). Вам точно нужен генератор для реализации вашей идеи? И судя по двум вызовам bot.on в генераторе вы не совсем разобрались с работой telegram-bot

Comment: Да я и не спорю, просто решения кроме как генератором я не нашел, смотрел в сторону ForceReply, но мне показалось что он немного не вписываеться в эту задачу.
bot.on("message" ) - обработка входящего сообщения от пользователя или есть другие способы
Если можете посоветовать альтернативу буду очень благодарен.

Comment: К сожалению, здесь ничем не помогу. Извиняйте )

Comment: Я не совсем понял как использовать yield,
Бот задал вопрос, ждет ответа, получил, запустил следующий next'ом и так далее.
 function* gen() {
 let ask1 = yield () =>{ bot.sendMessage(id, "Вопрос 1?");
  bot.on("message", msg => {
      fname = msg.text;
      generator.next();
    });}

  let ask2 = yield  () =>{ bot.sendMessage(id, "Вопрос 2?");
      bot.on("message", msg => {
        sname = msg.text;});
        generator.next();}
...
  }

** Вызов generator.next() вызывает исполнение половины первой строки генератора yield ** - а почему так? Обязательны ли аргументы .next()?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дерево сценариев в telegram-боте php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683506/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-php)

Comment: Не понял в чем проблема, после получения ответы вы не можете сразу задать следующий?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте реализовать это через промисы. Каждый вопрос оборачивая в `promise.then(someThing => {})` ну или еще вариант через async await