# Сценарии в PyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telegram-bot

В университе дали задание - написать бота для условного МЧС на базе [PyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#the-listener-mechanism). Требования к боту таковы, что он должен понимать тип чрезвычайной ситуации(пожар, наводнение, etc.), запрашивать координаты у пользователя(в Телеге их можно отправлять боту через гуглокарты) и класть их в базу. У меня возникло недопонимание при работе с PyTelegramBotAPI. Итак, как я себе представляю код этого бота - он должен распознать тип ЧС, и в зависимости от типа установить специальный флаг(переменную). Для этого я написал функцию:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def recognizeEmergency(message):
    if(message.text == 'Пожар') or (message.text == 'Пожар!') or (message.text == 'Горим!'):
        recognizeFire(message)
```

Здесь всё довольно просто и очевидно - если `message.text` равняется `%название-чс%`, то я отправляю пользователя в другую функцию:

```
def recognizeFire(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мы правильно поняли, что у вас пожар?')
    confirmFire()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def confirmFire(message):
    if(message.text == 'Да'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Принято. Отправьте нам Ваши координаты')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошиблись? Попробуйте ещё раз')
```

Это функция-подтверждение на тот случай, если человек вдруг ошибся. Так вот, суть моего вопроса заключается в том, а как заставить ждать ввода? Ибо сейчас при вызове функции она моментально выводит 'Ошиблись? Попробуйте ещё раз.'. Почему?

Comment: просто интересно, а что это за университет такой продвинутый?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дерево сценариев в telegram-боте php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683506/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-php)

Comment: Ну судя по коду такой вывод происходит потому что message.text пустой. Вам до if нужно вставить дополнительную проверку.