# отправка данных telegram боту

Tags: python, telegram-bot, raspberry-pi

Есть бот. Помогает в автоматизации дома. Реализован через long polling, фреймворк  telepot. Появилось желание добавить возможность помогать учитывать показания счетчиков расхода воды. Я себе представляю это так : захожу в соответствующий пункт меню бот просит показания "холодная вода" я отправил, потом "горячая вода" отправил. Как сделать так чтобы бот ждал от меня эти данные? И понимал, что это именно про воду? Или это как-то по другому реализуется?
Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дерево сценариев в telegram-боте php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683506/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-php)

Comment: @Anatol, не думаю, что правильно закрывать как дубликат вопроса на другом языке?

Comment: @Quertiy так разницы нет, на каком языке. Смысл вопроса в концептуальном решении проблемы и это очень типичная проблема для новичков. Это реализуется примерно одинаково на любом языке, тк апи одно и то же, синтаксис плюс-минус отличается

Comment: Автор сам как считает, дубликат или нет?

Comment: вопросы конечно по своей сути одинаковые, но здесь представлено ещё одно решение - команда с аргументом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишите хэндлер, который будет ловить команду с аргументом, например, /cold 12345
По команде будет ясно, холодная или горячая вода, аргументом будет передаваться цифры-показания (например 5 цифр). Простой пример:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['cold', 'hot'])
def water_message(message):
  args = message.text.split()
  result = re.search(r'\d{5}', str(args[1])) #ищем во втором аргументе совпадение по регулярному выражению
  if result:
    if args[0] == 'cold':
      .........
    else:
      .........
```