# Обработка текста из команды Telegram на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Доброго времени суток.

Делаю бота на Python'e и для реализации некоторых функций требуется, чтобы текст после ввода команды записывался в переменную, а от туда скажем в документ (с сохранением в `.txt` проблем нет).
По коду, что ниже, текст введенный после любой команды обрабатываются первым декоратором `(@)`, что нужно поправить, чтобы текст поступаюший после определенной команды обрабатывался по заданным условиям?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['1'])
def handle_text (message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ввести данные")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    txt = message.text
    patch = '/Users/IGRSSV/PycharmProjects/tgm2/userid/g.txt'
    v = open(patch, 'w')
    v.write(txt)
    v.close()
    print(txt)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "/w")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['w']) 
def handle_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нужно больше данных") 

@bot.message_handler()
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    txt = message.text  
    patch = '/Users/IGRSSV/PycharmProjects/tgm2/userid/w.txt' 
    v = open(patch, 'w')
    v.write(txt)
    v.close()
    print(txt)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "/age")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import telebot

token = ''
file_path = ''
client_status = {}
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

def save(data):
    with open(file_path, 'a') as log_file:
        log_file.write(data)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['begin'])
def begin(message):
    client_id = message.from_user.id
    client_status[client_id] = 'wait_for_data'
    bot.send_message(chat_id=client_id, text='Enter data: ')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handler(message):
    client_id = message.from_user.id
    if client_id in client_status and client_status[client_id] == 'wait_for_data':
        save(message.text) # сохраняем данные
        bot.send_message(chat_id=client_id, text='Done.')
        del client_status[client_id]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Суть в том, чтобы запоминать действия пользователя, к примеру в словаре, где ключ это его `id` а значение это пред. действие, в данном случае команда.

Comment: Спасибо, все вроде работает, но почему бот отрабатывает только первую команду в коде?

Comment: @Игорь если хотите больше - добавьте

Comment: я тоже решил,что добавление второй и последующих команд решит вопрос,но смотрите он не обрабатывает вторую команду и любую другую

Comment: @Игорь Я Вас не понимаю

Comment: Команды кроме :
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['begin'])
не обрабатываются, так как длина комментариев ограничена , вышлю Вам код в лс

Comment: @Игорь хорошо, жду