# telebot работа с хендлерами

Tags: python, telebot

Есть комманда для бота, которая получает список бесед в ВК

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["getConf"])
    def handle_text(message):
```

После этого, бот получает этот список и предлагает пользователю выбрать на клавиатуре одну из конф (в этом же хендлере ещё один)

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def handle_text1(message):
```

После этого, если ввести другую команду, которая не принадлежит этому хендлеру, она не будет работать. Как выйти из него?

Comment: Ничего не понятно, опишите задачу подробнее

Comment: Как я уже выше написал, в боте есть комманда getConf. Её суть заключается в получении списка личных диалогов (в массив) пользователя ВК. После этого бот делает из этого массива клавиатуру и предлагает пользователю выбрать один из диалогов (т.е., внутри хендлера с командой getConf, лежит ещё один, на отлавливание текста, который пользователь введёт, выбрав кнопку на той клавиатуре). И после этого, введя любой текст, его будет перехватывать тот хендлер, который лежит в хендлере (предназначенный для клавиатуры) с отлавливанием команды getConf. А не любой другой. Как его переключить?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

То, что вы описали, называется [FSM (Finite-state machine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Кратко: вам нужно запомнить что ввёл юзер, и исходя из этого действовать дальше.

Небольшой пример с использованием [Redis](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis):

```
import redis
from telebot import TeleBot

bot = TeleBot(os.environ.get('token'))
r = redis.from_url(os.environ.get("REDIS_URL"))


@bot.message_handler(commands=['command'])
def handle_command(message):
    r.set(message.chat.id, 'next')
    bot.reply_to(message, text='Some text')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: r.get(m.chat.id) == 'next')
def handle_text(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, text='Hurray!')
```

Данную функциональность можно реализовать с использованием обычных словарей, как например в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746598/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-telegram-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python/746627#746627).