# Реализация пошаговых действий в боте Телеграм

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Проблема состоит в том, что нельзя точно связывать последовательность действий. 
Суть такая. Мы создаем меню в боте. И допустим нужно, что бы появилась возможность сохранять фотографию. В меню бота нажимается кнопка добавить фото и следующим постом нужно отправить пост с фото. И на словах казалось бы все просто, но как это реализовать на практике. При нажатии на кнопку да и  при отправке фото, нет маркеров которые смогли бы связать эти 2 действия. Пишу бота на php. Например, когда я создаю некую анкету, я могу параметры передавать скрытно, в каллбек запросе, и последовательно их записывать в базу, опираясь на ID сообщения, но что делать с фото или текстом. Может записывать временные файлы с действиями, и привязывать их например ко времени. Кто писал что то подобное, поделитесь опытом.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дерево сценариев в telegram-боте (строгая последовательность вопросов/ответов)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683506/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: всё куда проще, используйте `ForceReply`

Comment: @Anatol можно подробнее, не могу разобраться как правильно  прописать, по разному пробовал, просто появляется возможность отвечать на сообщение, но это сложно для восприятия пользователями, ни кто не поймет это.

Comment: *не могу разобраться как правильно прописать* - что прописать?

Comment: *это сложно для восприятия пользователями, ни кто не поймет это* - странно, что вы так считаете. Ответ на конкретное сообщение как раз и есть самый очевидный способ передачи требуемой информации

Comment: @Anatol даже опираясь на то как люди в чатах общаются, редко когда используют ответ на сообщение. Если бы я для себя делал, то да, я бы так может и реализовал. Но для пользователей хочется, что бы после нажатия на кнопку, можно было следующим сообщением отправить ответ. Я давно нашел решение и оно уже работает, но я всегда в поисках совершенства и с радостью б перешел на что то более удобное с точки зрения обработки этих данных.

Comment: *как люди в чатах общаются* - не знаю что вы там себе понапридумывали или с какими людьми общаетесь, но эту фичу придумали именно из-за удобства, и это настолько удобно, что даже ватсап это реализовал. Мои боты в проде работают уже не первый год именно по такой схеме, а если кто и не пользуется, так вероятнее всего по незнанию

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для реализации вашей задумки нужно сохранять состояние каждого чата на вашем сервере, где запущен бот. Например, пользователь из чата с id = 12345 выбрал пункт меню "Добавить фото", ваш бот запомнил это в своей БД (скажем, MySQL). На следующем шаге бот уже знает, как обработать вновь полученное из того же чата. Для более общего поинмания идеи стоит ознакомиться с понятием [конечного автомата](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82).

Comment: Я уже что то подобное стал делать. Перед тем как все данные записать в базу, я создаю временный файл с названием в виде ID пользователя, так каждому пользователю будет свой файл. И при первом запросе вношу туда номер сообщения, и далее когда дописываю данные, просто сравниваю текущий  номер сообщения с тем номером, но плюс некое число, которое соответствует шагу действия.  И так и действия не перепутаются, и если нажать не ту команду то данные в файле обнуляются, а как все готово будет то все в базу пишу. Нагрузка на базу правда была б минимальной, но все ж это временные данные, пусть в файле