# Как реализовать мини-бд вопрос-ответ?

Tags: java, база-данных, telegram-bot

Я хочу написать Tg-бота, и мне надо что бы он отвечал на сообщения. Я могу сделать это с помощью `if-else`, но это будет очень громоздко.

Как примерно это реализовать?

Comment: у вас шаблонные ответы на шаблонные вопросы?

Comment: @Виктор, мне не понятно даже в каком направлении искать. Причем тут шаблоны?

Comment: что вы собираетесь искать в БД? конкретный вопрос (побуквенное совпадение) или вы ещё анализируете вопрос и отвечаете исходя из контекста?

Comment: Буквенное совпадение.

Comment: пар вопрос-ответ сколько?

Comment: @Виктор без разницы, но должно быть много

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70001/discussion-between--and--).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/683506/183842

Comment: Вы, наверное, рановато взялись за эту задачу. Сам факт, что вы не можете сформулировать вопрос, об этом говорит. Лучше бы вам поупражняться сначала на каких-то более простых примерах. Это не критика, а совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создать файл `answer.properties` (например)
2. Записать туда список вопросы и ответы, если в вопросе или ответе возможно наличие символов `=,-,:` или похожих то самое простое на первой строке писать вопрос, на следующей ответ.
3. При запуске боту загрузить список вопрос-ответ в Map

   ```
   Map<String, String> allAnswer = new HashMap<>();

   public void init(){
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("путь к фалу"));
       String question;
       while( (question = reader.readLine()) != null){
           String answer = reader.readLine();
           allAnswer.put(question, answer);
       }
   }
   ```

   В данном случае ответственность за валидность файла (у каждого вопроса должен быть ответ) лежит на вас.
4. Создать метод в который приходит вопрос от пользователя и возвращается ответ:

   ```
   public String answer(String question){
       String answer = allAnswer.get(question);
       if (answer == null)
           return "нет ответа";
       return answer;
   }
   ```

Comment: Что лучше всего использовать вместо хеш-списков? Если я правильно помню, слова, которые я туда занесу, будут не  в порядке занесения, а в другом порядке.

Comment: Лучше для вашей задачи ничего нет. Использование например LinkedHashMap замедлит поиск по ключу

Answer (score 0):

В боте может быть много команд, и у каждой команды может быть много параметров. Можно для каждой команды добавить слушателя, и реализовать его обработчик. 
Теперь вы можете написать switch, и при необходимости (при нужной команде) извещать слушателя о пришедшем сообщении.

В обработчике будет обработка параметров команды, некоторые действия, и ответ. Обработчик также должен возвращать сообщение -- успешное, или с ошибкой.

См. паттерн "Наблюдатель" ([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Наблюдатель_(шаблон_проектирования)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)))

Делать таблицу для команд я не вижу смысла. А вот для обработки параметров -- наверно, стоит.