# Построение диалога вопрос-ответ в телеграм боте

Tags: java, telegram-bot

```
     if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("/data")) {
            SendMessage message = new SendMessage()
                    .setChatId(chat_id)
                    .setText("Введите дату ");

            try {
                execute(message);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }message.setText("Введите год");
            try {
                execute(message);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String date=update.getMessage().getText();
            System.out.println(date);
```

как победить проблему,чтобы выводилась не команда /data ,а следующее сообщение от пользователя.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дерево сценариев в telegram-боте (строгая последовательность вопросов/ответов)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683506/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Смогли решит проблему?