# Telegram BOT: нужно получить текст из след. сообщения ( Python )

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Я еще совсем новичок.
Использую pyTelegramBotAPI:

Пользователь вводит некоторую команду, бот присылает сообщение с примером как нужно вводить данные и ждёт следующего сообщения, получив записывает в переменную. Вопрос заключается в том как получить новое сообщение?

Мой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda c:True, content_types=['text'])
def info_message(message):
    msg = message.text.lower() 
    if msg == 'добавить примечание':   
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Следующее сообщение станет примечанием:') 
        note = message.text
print(note)
```

Возвращает 'добавить примечание', а мне нужно следующее сообщение.

Comment: покажите весь код

Comment: Код 500 строк....
Что именно показать?

Comment: в чём конкретно проблема? как понять "как получить новое сообщение"? с сервера как получить новый апдейд или что?

Comment: и что значит "возвращает *добавить примечание*"? куда возвращает, печатает в консоль?

Comment: (да, печатает в консоль) Я пишу пользователю  'Следующее сообщение станет примечанием:' и пользователь шлет боту любое сообщение, как мне получить текст этого сообщения (которое пользователь написал боту после того как увидел надпись  'Следующее сообщение станет примечанием:')?

Comment: ну а как вы остальные получаете-то? так же и получайте следующее, не понимаю в чём проблема

Comment: в консоль печатает потому что вы сами ему говорите это печатать - `if msg == 'добавить примечание'` `note = message.text` `print(note)`

Comment: если вопрос о том, как выстроить сценарий взаимодействия пользователя с ботом, то [на этот вопрос уже отвечали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/683506/183842)

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1258967/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E?newreg=0feddeaae3fb497389f0faf400526a1f Оно работает