# Как получить ответ от юзера и записать его в переменную

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Практикуюсь в написании бота в телеграмм. Использую telebot.

```
    if message.text == "One":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "input first num")
    #Здесь нужно получить число и записать его в переменную
```

В коде все описал что я хочу получить.

Answer (score 2):

Можно перенаправить пользователя на следующий шаг с помощью функции `register_next_step_handler`.

Пример:

```py
bot = telebot.TeleBot('superpupertoken123')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])  #реагирует на любые сообщения
def test(message):
     if message.text == 'One':    #Если содержимое == 'One',то 
          bot.reply_to(message, 'Введите текст')   #Bot reply 'Введите текст'
          @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])  #Создаём новую функцию ,реагирующую на любое сообщение
          def message_input_step(message):
               global text  #объявляем глобальную переменную
               text = message.text
               bot.reply_to(message, f'Ваш текст: {message.text}')
          bot.register_next_step_handler(message, message_input_step) #добавляем следующий шаг, перенаправляющий пользователя на message_input_step
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его как решение.